# Dart with desktop HTML application frameworks

Tags: javascript, html, dart, desktop

I'm planning to create a cross platform desktop application with Dart.
Because there's no ready built frameworks supporting Dart yet, i have to compile Dart to Javascript first.
I cannot develop completly in Dartium since the desktop frameworks built around HTML5 provide some custom Javascript API's (file system access, native library support, etc.) which i'm planning to use.

I've found the following frameworks which might suit my needs but i'm looking for best practices when developing with Dart.

- [**node-webkit**](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit): a fusion of Node and the Webkit browser engine. Provides many packages in the form of NPM. Node and Webkit shares the same thread so it's efficient in terms of communication between the different worlds. Writing and accessing native modules from Javascript [seems problematic](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Build-native-modules-with-nw-gyp). Has good documentation. There's [node-webkit.dart](https://github.com/luizmineo/node-webkit.dart) to access some of the API's from Dart.
- [**XULRunner**](https://www.google.hu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/XULRunner&ei=vDUoU6X2KZGihge9hYCwAg&usg=AFQjCNHqqPYf4ehj0MOUkEY47Pb7DWWfCw&sig2=McTf0AWj_g_EqCWUo0l2-Q&bvm=bv.62922401,d.ZG4): The Gecko engine behind Mozilla products as a reusable framework. Provides it's very own UI descriptor (XUL). Has an easier support for native modules ([js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes)). Seems well documented on MDN. No Dart library written to support development yet.
- [**TideKit**](https://www.tidekit.com/)/[**TideSDK**](https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK): Supports many languages (Dart might be supported later on [[link]](https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/issues/245) [[link]](https://twitter.com/matthewdeaners/status/413022642782748672)). Built around Webkit. Seems well documented. Cannot seem to find pub packages supporting it.

Maybe there are some other options i haven't seen yet. I've excluded projects like [AppJs](http://appjs.com/) (dead), and [Cappucino](http://www.cappuccino-project.org/) (OSX only).

Comment: What about Chrome packaged apps? Seems to be going in the direction that they look like native applications. See also http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/chrome I guess there are no best practices yet to build desktop apps because Dart is currently primary focused on the web. Desktop apps may be targeted in the future though.

Comment: @Günther Zöchbauer: I have commented this at sunglim's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the first option.

[Chrome Packaged App](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps)

You can write Chrome Packaged App with Dart.

dart2js makes it possible to compile dart code to javascript.

and thanks to [chrome.dart](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/chrome) package, chrome APIs are availble.

Spark is nice example. See https://github.com/dart-lang/spark

Comment: I know about Chrome packaged apps. But as far as i know you have to install Chrome first to install my own app. The frameworks i have linked in the description focus on creating apps which are working on their own.

Comment: Or maybe it's not that simple: http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/127055-google-building-a-way-to-use-chrome-apps-without-running-chrome

Answer (score 8):

One option is the [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) framework. Originally created by GitHub for their Atom editor, it allows you to build cross-platform applications for Linux, OS X, or Windows, using web technologies. There is an available [Dart wrapper](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/electron) as well. However, this wrapper lacks complete support for the API, and doesn't appear to be under active development.

Another method of using Electron is to call all the electron and node methods via `dart:js` interop. I've had more success with this method than the library.

Electron uses a main process, stored in `main.js`, to run the app, and create new `BrowserWindow`s, which load your html. I've found it easier to simply write this file in Javascript, as wrapping too many JS methods is a pain, and this script is relatively light. However, you can use a `main.dart` file and simply build it with dart2js. Electron will be happy as long as it can find a `main.js` file.

You can essentially build pages for the app just as you would a regular webpage. You can write it in dart, debug in Dartium, and compile to Javascript for testing it in your app. Of course, your code can't access node APIs from the browser, so you'll have to build the app every time you want to use these. (If anyone has a better way, please point it out!)

One final caveat: Dart's IO libraries won't work with Electron. This is a bit of a drawback, as accessing files is important for pretty much any application. Your best bet will be to use node's filesystem library through dart-js interop. At times, this may feel like a bit of a hack (for example, when working with callbacks), but it gets the job done.

Comment: Has there anything changed from 2015? How would you use Dart for desktop apps for now?